# Disable numbering of the appendix elements in KOMA

Tags: numbering, koma-script, appendix

I am using the `scrreprt` KOMA documentclass. I want to completely disable the numbering of the chapters and sections in the appendix. I already read the documentation but i don't understand how to do it.

Currently the Appendix looks like this:

[image]

But I want to completely disable the numbering of the chapters and sections in the appendix so it looks like this:

```
Anhang                                                 65
  Kommunikationsmatrizen...............................65
  Konfigurationsdatei..................................67
  Benchmark Tabellen und Box-Whisker-Plots.............68
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `scrreprt` documentclass but in general the `\secnumdepth` counter controls which sectional divisions are (un)numbered.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

will result in no divisions being numbered, but

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

will result in divisions `\subsection` and above being numbered.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I am unsure if this is the intended way to do it in the scrreprt documentclass but it works perfectly in my document.

Comment: I just spotted a issue with this solution. The table numbering stops working correctly because the missing chapter number: `Tabelle .1.: Tabellentitel`.  Do you maybe know a way how to fix this?

Comment: @mab0189 I don't know how to fix this. Please ask another question regarding the `scrreprt` class. If chapters aren't numbered then by default, I assume,  there will be no number before the caption title. I know  nothing about the class.

Comment: @mab0189 How should the tables be numbered in appendix? Tabelle A.1 or Tabelle 1? Or maybe better: Should the tables be numbered consecutively throughout the document?